# How to get the latest two dates from table for each unique id

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

| unique_id | date |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1/1/2023 |
| A | 3/1/2023 |
| A | 5/1/2023 |
| B | 1/1/2023 |
| B | 2/1/2023 |
| B | 3/1/2023 |
| B | 4/1/2023 |
| C | 1/1/2023 |

I want my data to look like this

| unique_id | latest_date | 2nd_latest_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 5/1/2023 | 3/1/2023 |
| B | 4/1/2023 | 3/1/2023 |
| C | 1/1/2023 | Null |

Comment: There is a much better solution if you are OK with the result being in rows instead of columns. In this case you can simply use GROUP BY, ORDER BY and LIMIT/TOP.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using conditional aggregation and the row_number function as the following:

```
select unique_id,
       max(case when rn=1 then date end) as latest_date,
       max(case when rn=2 then date end) as _2nd_latest_date
from
(
  select *,
    row_number() over (partition by unique_id order by date desc) as rn
  from table_name
) T
group by unique_id
order by unique_id
```